# JAVA - SQL online database

Tags: java, sql, database, cloud

I'm trying to write a code where i need to keep some data in database tables.
I have learned how to use SQL. My problem is that I want this program to run on different computers while having access to the same database.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run an SQL server on a computer (ie: with mySQL, SQL Server, etc.). You will run queries against the tables that are stored on this database. There are already a lot of resources online with making a database connection to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep database system running in a machine, and instead of pointing to localhost in your JDBC URL, point to the machine's IP Address.

Comment: Could you please explain. A bit more about this ?

Comment: 'Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Mondial";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
stmt = conn.createStatement();'

Comment: OK, then if you install MySQL in another server, instead of the localhost in jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Mondial, you will have to put the ip address of the machine where you installed MySQL Server.

Comment: And if I want it to be on my computer but have other people access it ?

Comment: So how do I set it up ?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend setting up a script on a host machine and letting it communicate with the database, and have your program communicate with the script. This way, you won't have to keep your database login credentials in your Java program, which could be dangerous.